# Caching web page

Tags: php, performance, facebook, caching, twitter

Does websites like twitter and facebook ( where the content change often ) use caching ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. A commonly used cache software is [memcached](http://memcached.org/)

You should read up on caching and how it works and how it does not. [Here is a link to a very large cache tutorial/faq](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these sites heavily rely on (different type of) caching. They likely using special solutions that extremely fine-tuned to fit their needs because every kind of web applications has their weakness.

[High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) has great articles in [this topic](http://highscalability.com/blog/category/example).

Answer (score 2):

Look at this article:

http://royal.pingdom.com/2010/06/18/the-software-behind-facebook/

> [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is by now one of the most
>   famous pieces of software on the
>   internet. It’s a distributed memory
>   caching system which Facebook (and a
>   ton of other sites) use as a caching
>   layer between the web servers and
>   MySQL servers (since database access
>   is relatively slow). Through the
>   years, Facebook has made a ton of
>   optimizations to Memcached and the
>   surrounding software (like optimizing
>   the network stack).